# Curl авторизация nnm-club.ru

Tags: curl, php, авторизация

Здравствуйте.

Вот уже 2-й день сижу и не пойму, почему не работает. Уже как ни менял код, все равно не авторизуется. Прошу помочь, ну что тут не так?

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://nnm-club.ru/forum/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://nnm-club.ru/forum/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=nick&password=Qwerty123&autologin=1&returnto=');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",curl_exec($curl));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://nnm-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=480539');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://nnm-club.ru/forum/');

echo iconv("windows-1251","utf-8",curl_exec($curl));

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Не поддерживает твой хостинг curl/ скорее всего

Comment: Нет, его пример скрипта нерабочий, неверно составлен post запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример с моим логином и паролем:

```
<?php

$url = "http://nnm-club.ru/forum/login.php";
$referer = "http://nnm-club.ru/forum/";
$user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
$post = "username=Andrey+z668&password=dAJsB1lu&redirect=&login=%C2%F5%EE%E4";
$header [] = "Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1";
$header [] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";
$header [] = "Accept-Charset: Windows-1251, utf-8, *;q=0.1";
$header [] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate, identity, *;q=0";
//$proxy = "121.11.64.13:80";

$user_cookie = "cookies.txt";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```